# Unable to update the state of my app, console.log inside reducer shows that object has changed, but the state remains same

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Playing with redux has got me very confusing. Some how its getting so difficult to update the state of just one key in object.

A action is dispatched when user checks the checkbox inside of the component. When it is checked the status of the product should change from NEW to RESERVED:

// ProductRow.js

```
const ProductRow = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },

  render () {
    const { code, name, imageUrl, description } = this.props.item.product
    const {status} = this.props.item
    const {onChange} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={code}>
          <input type='checkbox' id={code} onClick={onChange} value={status} />
          <img src={imageUrl} />
          <div className='name'>{name}</div>
          <div className='description'>{description}</div>
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

The parent component of ProductRow is ProductList:

```
const ProductList = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    dispatchSetStatusToReservedForItem: PropTypes.func
  },

  handleProductCheckBoxClick (item) {
    if (document.getElementById(item.product.code).checked) {
      this.props.dispatchSetStatusToReservedForItem(item)
    }
  },

  render () {
    const {items} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {
          items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <ProductRow key={item.id} onChange={this.handleProductCheckBoxClick.bind(this, item)} item={item} />
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

When the checkbox is ticked i get the alerted by console.log inside of reducer and its shows the right output that is the right object inside of the array 'item' has changed, but somehow it is not reflected in the UI and rect developer tools.

//Reducer
    const DEFAULT_STATE = {
      shoppingCartData: shoppingCartData
    }

```
const setStatusToReserved = (state, action) => {
  const {items} = state.shoppingCartData.data

  items.map(item => {
    if(action.item.id === item.id) {
      console.log(Object.assign({},action.item, {status: 'RESERVED'}))
      return Object.assign({}, action.item, {status: 'RESERVED'})
    }
  })
}

const rootReducer = (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case ACTIONS.SET_STATUS_TO_RESERVED:
      return setStatusToReserved(state, action)

    default:
      return DEFAULT_STATE
  }
}

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: From your example code, it looks like you haven't hooked up `mapStateToProps`.  This is how you get the changes from the redux into your component.  You can start reading about it here: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change a part of your state, you need to create a new object reference for your state. With the way you're doing it, your old state will still `===` your new state, so there's no way for redux to know it changed.

Additionally, your `setStatusToReserved` function doesn't return anything at all!

Your state shouldn't be as deeply nested as it is, and I think there's more work to be done, but a step forward is something like:

```
const setStatusToReserved = (state, action) => {
  const {items} = state.shoppingCartData.data

  const newItems = items.map(item => {
    if(action.item.id === item.id) {
      console.log(Object.assign({},action.item, {status: 'RESERVED'}))
      return Object.assign({}, action.item, {status: 'RESERVED'})
    }
  })

  return {
    ...state,
    shoppingCartData: {
      ...shoppingCartData.data,
      items: newItems
    }
  }
}
```

I would highly suggest watching the [Egghead Redux series](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) which is free and addresses all of these problems.

Comment: Thanks Andy, you are right, I am making it much complicated. I have a big data.json file that I use as Default_state and pass to all components. I think its a bad idea, as many of my components use static data. Only the product items need two way binding. You think it is better I pass the rest data my importing the data.json and passing as props and connect only ProductList to redux?

Comment: In your top level state object, each key a specific slice of the state that one reducer controls (or nested reducers control). I would suggest watching the videos. Stackoverflow is not good for back and forth type questions.

Comment: If this answered your question, click the empty check mark next to it to mark it as correct. If it didn't, can you refine the question?

Comment: hey andy thanks the videos, really helped me out, i made passed inital state to the store and the state that i wanted to change. The rest I passed it via props.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the reducer much, and I am only getting the state from the store (by setting the initial state) that I want to change and made Product List my smart component(as that is the only one I want the state to be changed). I think the change I made to reducer and picking up my smart component carefully helped. Thanks for the video recommendation, Dan's videos helped a lot.

```
import { ACTIONS } from './actions'

/**
 * Returns an updated array with check product status set to RESERVED
 * @param state
 * @param action
 * @return {[*,*,*]}
 */
const setStatusToReserved = (state, action) => {
  let updateStatus = Object.assign({}, action.item, {status: 'RESERVED'})
  let index = state.indexOf(action.item)

  return [...state.slice(0, index), updateStatus, ...state.slice(index + 1)]
}

/**
 * Returns an updated array with check product status set to NEW
 * @param state
 * @param action
 * @return {[*,*,*]}
 */
const setStatusToNew = (state, action) => {
  let updateStatus = Object.assign({}, action.item, {status: 'NEW'})
  let index = state.indexOf(action.item)

  return [...state.slice(0, index), updateStatus, ...state.slice(index + 1)]
}

/**
 * Function that takes the current state and action and return new state
 * Initial state is set to product items
 * @param state
 * @param action
 * @return {{}}
 */
const rootReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.SET_STATUS_TO_RESERVED:
      return setStatusToReserved(state, action)

    case ACTIONS.SET_STATUS_TO_NEW:
      return setStatusToNew(state, action)

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[PROD_FORM_DETAILS_SUCCESS]: (state, { payload: { ProdDetailsData } }) => 
        {
            console.log(" reducer ===================== " , catalogueProductDetailsData);
        return {
      ...state,
      catalogueProductDetailsData,
      isFetching: false,
    }},

[CREATE_USER_FORM]: (state, {}) => {
      console.log(" reducer =======CREATE_USER_FORM ============== ");
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
      };
    },

   //Without console

    [CREATE_USER_FORM]: (state, {}) => ({
      ...state,
      isFetching: true,
    }),
```